# React: Can I match the div id with Props

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I want to say,

```
componentDidMount() {
  if (x == y) {
    var x = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this)
    var y = div.id
    $('#y').append(x)
  }
}
```

If the div id is equal to the name of the node, then append the node onto that div.

I am making a calendar application that and each event is a separate component that must be mapped onto a div with an id of 9:00AM, 10:00AM, 11:00AM, 12:00PM etc.

This.props.start_time returns

```
12:00AM
```

Comment: Can you explain further. I've tried this and it does not work. Thanks!

Comment: It says "Uncaught ReferenceError: div is not defined"

Comment: @CodeYogi Where is the div? Can you post more of your code?

Comment: You never define it, so of course it is not defined... Pro tip: always use `;` at the end of the lines. One day you will run into a bug which you won't find if you don't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what worked:

```
  componentDidMount() {

    var x= ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this)
    var y = this.props.time
  $('#' + y).append(x)
  }
```

Comment: This is awful: why don't you add it with react?

Comment: How would I do that?